# Bandwidth Consumption

Tags: java, wowza

I am currently getting bandwidth usage per session for RTMP, HTTP and RTP like this:

```
//RTMP
public void onStreamDestroy(IMediaStream stream) {
        if ( stream.getClient() != null){

            IOPerformanceCounter perf = stream.getMediaIOPerformance();

            Long outbytes = perf.getMessagesOutBytes();
        }
    }

//HTTP
public void onHTTPSessionDestroy(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
        if ( httpSession != null){

                    IOPerformanceCounter perf = httpSession.getIOPerformanceCounter();
                    Long outbytes = perf.getMessagesOutBytes(); 
                }
    }


    //RTP
    public void onRTPSessionDestroy(RTPSession rtpSession) {

        if ( rtpSession != null){

            IOPerformanceCounter perf = rtpSession.getIOPerformanceCounter();

            Long outbytes = perf.getMessagesOutBytes();

        }
    }
```

When I compare my usage with the hosting provider, it is very different.  My usage is lower than my provider.

Is this correct way to get bandwidth usage?

Comment: Looks ok to me. How much is a difference? Do they give you per-protocol stats from SP point of view or just total amount? Is it same pattern every day?